# RISC-V: is there a faster emulator than QEMU?

Tags: emulation, qemu, riscv

We are installing applications into Fedora, using QEMU, for RISC-V instruction set.  So, we boot the RISC-V version of Fedora v29  on QEMU v. 2.12.92.  Then need to install Python dependencies, using pip3 and DNF.  But it goes *very* slowly.  Is there a faster way?  Such as using Spike, or risvemu, etc?

Comment: I tried both Debian ARM64 and RISC-V via QEMU. Both feel slow comparing to the host OS. But RISC-V is 10-40% faster than ARM64!!! I used the following images https://people.debian.org/~gio/dqib/

Answer (score 3):

QEMU's user-mode emulation is significantly faster than the system-mode emulation, and also has the advantage of avoiding virtualized IO.  Debian provides an [example](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation) of how to use this support transparently, there is probably similar support for your favorite distribution.

To the best of my knowledge, there is currently no system-mode simulation that is both faster than QEMU and supports enough of a platform to boot Linux.

Comment: Thanks Palmer.  We'll look to see if there's some way to take advantage, as we pull in OpenCV-contrib-python.